# how to add formula to a column contains values

Tags: excel

for example, in column A, I have a 500 cells (A1:A500) that contain values, and I need to add up column A : column C without creating a new column because i need to show the orignal column A values within the formula,

eg:

A1 = 753; B1 = -100; C1 = 200

I need a formula in A1 become ==> A1 = +753+B1+C1

I need to show the calculation logic within the formula by keeping the column A values

how can i do without manually add the formula each cell?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBA along these lines

```
Sub test()
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    cel.Formula = "=" & cel.Value & "+B" & cel.Row & "+C" & cel.Row

Next cel

End Sub
```

As suggested in the comments, here is the R1C1 notation version, which is a bit more compact and runs faster.

```
For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    cel.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & cel.Value & "+RC[1]+RC[2]"

Next cel
```

Comment: Might benefit from a R1C1 style Formula. In performance and in my opinion clarity.

Comment: Thus why I said in my opinion, But the more important factor is performance over a large range you wouldn't want to call the worksheet for the row property of each cell twice for every iteration. However it could be avoided with a For loop in place of the For Each loop.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the R1C1 notation above.